# Cual es la mejor forma de crear un buscador que te filtre productos de mongodb

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Estoy en un proyecto en clase, en el que tenemos que filtrar los productos(coches), por tipo, region y los campos que queramos. Conseguimos hacerlo por un parametro, cogemos un parametro y nos filtra productos por nombre por ejemplo, pero se nos complica cuando queremos filtrar por mas detalles.
Os dejo un ejemplo de la forma filtrando solo un parametro y os dejo la forma que estoy probando con mas de un parametro, a ver si me podeis ayudar, ya que esta ultima no me funciona, la encontré por la web y tampoco sé si la estoy ejecutando correctamente.

Filtrando por un parametro(funciona)

Controlador y su funcion:

```
CarController.searchCar = async(req,res) =>{
    const searchResult = await carSearch({$text: {$search: req.body.searchCars, $caseSensitive: false}});
    res.render('cars/allCars', {cars:searchResult});
};

function carSearch(text){
    return Car.find(text).lean();
}
```

Y modelo:

```
const { Schema, model } = require ('mongoose');

const carSchema = new Schema({
    carBrand: {type: String,
        required:true},
    
    carModel: {type: String,
            required:true},
    
    leasingPrice: Number,
    
    carImage: {
            type: String},
            // required:true},
            
    seatsNumber: {type: Number,
            required:true},
    
    doorNumber: {type: Number,
            required:true},
    
    trunkSize: Number,
    
    co2Emissions: String,
    
    carType: String,
     
    
    airConditioner: String,
    
    transmissionType: {type: String,
            required:true},
    
    motorType: {type: String,
            required:true},
    
    availability: String,

    place: String
});

carSchema.index({"carBrand": "text", "carModel": "text", "motorType": "text", "place": "text"});

module.exports = model('Car', carSchema, 'cars');
```

Como os digo esta version con solo un parametro a buscar funciona perfectamente.

Ahora os comparto el codigo de como estamos intentando filtrar una busqueda por varios parametros:

Controlador:

```
CarController.searchCar = async(req,res) =>{
    const searchResult = await Car.find({carBrand: {$regex: '.*' + req.body.searchCars + '.*', $options: 'i'}, 
                                         carModel: {$regex: '.*' + req.body.searchCars + '.*', $options: 'i'},
                                         motorType: {$regex: '.*' + req.body.searchCars + '.*', $options: 'i'},
                                         place: {$regex: '.*' + req.body.searchCars + '.*', $options: 'i'}});
    res.render('cars/allCars', {cars:searchResult});
};
```

El modelo es el mismo que arriba, incluso el modelo de arriba esta adaptado para este ultimo ejemplo, por eso el index de busqueda no coincide con el ejemplo de un parametro, es solo para mostraros la forma que estamos utilizando.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Creo que deberías usar la [condición OR](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) para poder buscar en cada campo.

Comment: Si, con la condicion `or`, y puede que aggregate tambien sea lo que buscas.

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos